# FFI: Convert nullable pointer to option

Tags: rust, casting, ffi

I'm using rust-bindgen to access a C library from Rust. Some functions return nullable pointers to structs, which bindgen represents as

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn get_some_data() -> *const SomeStruct;
}
```

Now, for a higher level wrapper, I would like to convert this to a `Option<&'a SomeStruct>` with an appropriate lifetime. Due to the nullable pointer optimization, this is actually represented identically to `*const SomeStruct`. However, I couln't find any concise syntax to cast between the two. Transmuting

```rust
let data: Option<&'a SomeStruct> = unsafe { mem::transmute( get_some_data() ) };
```

and reborrowing

```rust
let data_ptr = get_some_data();
let data = if data_ptr.is_null() { None } else { unsafe { &*data_ptr } };
```

could be used. The [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/mem/fn.transmute.html) for `mem::transmute` state that

> transmute is incredibly unsafe. There are a vast number of ways to cause undefined behavior with this function. transmute should be the absolute last resort.

and recommends re-borrowing instead for

> Turning a *mut T into an &mut T

However, for the nullable pointer, this is quite clumsy as shown in the second example.

**Q:** Is there a more concise Syntax for this cast? Alternatively, is there a way to tell bindgen to generate

```rust
extern "C" {
    pub fn get_some_data() -> Option<&SomeStruct>;
}
```

directly?

Comment: I don't know if bindgen can be convinced to emit `fn get_some_data<'a>() -> Option<&'a _>`, but I feel it would probably be a mistake -- unless the data is actually of the `'static` lifetime, the signature would always be incorrect, so you'd have to stick it in a safe wrapper anyway. OTOH I can think of cases where `fn get_some_data() -> Option<&'static _>` would be useful, but only if the data is actually static, of course.

Comment: Right, I didn't think about the lifetime here, which is a good reason for bindgen not to generate the `Option` directly. In fact, for the function in question the lifetime is not `'static`, but bound to the lifetime of a handle (which I omitted in the function signature for the example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`<*const T>::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.as_ref)¹:

```
let data = unsafe { get_some_data().as_ref() };
```

Since a raw pointer may not point to a valid object of sufficient lifetime for any `'a`, `as_ref` is `unsafe` to call.

There is a corresponding [`as_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.pointer.html#method.as_mut) for `*mut T` → `Option<&mut T>`.

---

¹ This is a different `as_ref` from, for example, [`AsRef::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html#tymethod.as_ref) and [`Option::as_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref), both of which are common in safe code.

Comment: "Since the lifetime of the returned reference can be anything, it is unsafe to call." Well also because you are asserting that the pointer does, in fact, point to a valid object.

Comment: Arguably, every non-null pointer could be said to rhetorically point to a once-valid object whose lifetime might be expired :P But yes, you are right, maybe there's a better way to phrase that.

Comment: Not really. Reading uninitialized memory causes undefined behavior, which can cause a lot more issues than just reading a bad object when an optimizing compiler is involved. Furthermore, the pointer may not be aligned properly or point to unmapped memory which you can't even access. Thinking that the worst your gonna get is a bad object is naive and dangerous.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! Somehow, I didn't manage to google this or look at the right places in the documentation. The API states a well-defined lifetime in this case :)